# How to search a data set and return another cell value based on the response?

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a data set of people's names and corresponding numbers (columns M and I, respectively).  I am running a form that allow users enter in people's names.  I am having trouble finding a formula that will return me the corresponding number of the name entered.

For example, if Joe Shmoe's number is 123456, if someone were to submit "Shmoe, Joe" in A2, how could I get a formula to search the column Mx for "shmoe, joe" and return the value "123456" in Ix, whatever row x is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases people use INDEX/MATCH combination. In your case it will look like this:

```
=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(A2,M:M,0))
```

[image]

Bear in mind that the provided name must match **exactly**.